# How to use XMLUnit DiffBuilder to detect differences in attributes and lists of elements

Tags: java, xmlunit

I need to compare two XML strings, where there is potentially changes to arbitrary attributes within a tag, as well as tags arbitrarily inserted into, or deleted from, a sequence of tags.

I have found that if I use **ElementSelectors.byNameAndText** I get appropriate diffs for attribute changes, *unless there are sequence insertions or deletions*.

I have found that if I use **ElementSelectors.byNameAndAllAttributes** I get appropriate diffs for tags inserted into, or deleted from, a sequence of tags, *but not appropriate attributes change details*.

How do I combine these two diff generating mechanisms?

Control XML

```
String myControlXML =
    "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" +
    "<ns2:policy xmlns:ns2='com.xyz' version='2' id='ABCD'>" +
    "<ns2:widgets>" +
    "<ns2:widget name='foo' id='17'>" +
    "<ns2:desc text='Does foo widget stuff' version='2'/>" +
    "</ns2:widget>" +
    "<ns2:widget name='bar' id='19'>" +
    "<ns2:desc text='Does bar widget stuff' version='4'/>" +
    "</ns2:widget>" +
    "</ns2:widgets>" +
    "</ns2:policy>";
```

Test XML

```
String myTestXML1 =
    "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" +
    "<ns2:policy xmlns:ns2='com.xyz' version='13' id='ABCD'>" +
    "<ns2:widgets>" +
    "<ns2:widget name='foo' id='17'>" +
    "<ns2:desc text='Does foo widget stuff' version='2'/>" +
    "</ns2:widget>" +
    "<ns2:widget name='bzz' id='15'>" +
    "<ns2:desc text='Does bzz widget stuff' version='6'/>" +
    "</ns2:widget>" +
    "<ns2:widget name='bar' id='19'>" +
    "<ns2:desc text='Does bar widget stuff' version='4'/>" +
    "</ns2:widget>" +
    "</ns2:widgets>" +
    "</ns2:policy>";
```

Diff code

```
Diff myDiff7 = DiffBuilder.compare(myControlXML)
    .withTest(myTestXML1)
    .withNodeMatcher(new
        DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byNameAndAllAttributes))
    .build();
```

DIFF RESULTS 1

```
2 diffs
  - type = child
  - message = ns2:policy:Expected child '{com.xyz}policy' but was 'null' - comparing <ns2:policy...> at /policy[1] to <NULL>

  - type = child
  - message = ns2:policy:Expected child 'null' but was '{com.xyz}policy' - comparing <NULL> to <ns2:policy...> at /policy[1]
```

This seems to be saying 'some  attribute is different'

**With the ns2:policy lines matching,**

DIFF RESULTS 2

```
2 diffs
  - type = child nodelist sequence
  - message = widget:Expected child nodelist sequence '1' but was '2' - comparing <ns2:widget...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[2] to <ns2:widget...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[3]
  - type = child
  - message = widget:Expected child 'null' but was '{com.xyz}widget' - comparing <NULL> to <ns2:widget...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[2]
```

This seems to be correctly saying widget[2] was moved to widget[3] and a new widget[2] was added.

**With the initial XML values, but using ElementSelectors.byNameAndText instead of ElementSelectors.byNameAndAllAttributes**

DIFF RESULTS 3

```
6 diffs
  - type = attribute value
  - message = Expected attribute value '2' but was '13' - comparing <ns2:policy version="2"...> at /policy[1]/@version to <ns2:policy version="13"...> at /policy[1]/@version
  - type = attribute value
  - message = Expected attribute value '19' but was '15' - comparing <ns2:widget id="19"...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[2]/@id to <ns2:widget id="15"...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[2]/@id
  - type = attribute value
  - message = Expected attribute value 'bar' but was 'bzz' - comparing <ns2:widget name="bar"...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[2]/@name to <ns2:widget name="bzz"...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[2]/@name
  - type = attribute value
  - message = Expected attribute value 'Does bar widget stuff' but was 'Does bzz widget stuff' - comparing <ns2:desc text="Does bar widget stuff"...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[2]/desc[1]/@text to <ns2:desc text="Does bzz widget stuff"...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[2]/desc[1]/@text
  - type = attribute value
  - message = Expected attribute value '4' but was '6' - comparing <ns2:desc version="4"...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[2]/desc[1]/@version to <ns2:desc version="6"...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[2]/desc[1]/@version
  - type = child
  - message = Expected child 'null' but was '{com.xyz}widget' - comparing <NULL> to <ns2:widget...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[3]
```

This seems to be correctly comparing the ns2:policy line, but is incorrectly comparing the old widget 2 to the new widget 2, and indicating a new widget[3] was added.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Edit:

I found a partial answer here [XMLUnit-2.0 xpath doesn't ignoring the XML node order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61184818/xmlunit-2-0-xpath-doesnt-ignoring-the-xml-node-order)

```
Diff myDiff7a = DiffBuilder.compare(myControlXML)
    .withTest(myTestXML1)
    .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
        .whenElementIsNamed("widget").thenUse(
            (e1, e2) -> StringUtils.equals(e1.getAttribute("name"), e2.getAttribute("name")))
        .elseUse(ElementSelectors.byName)
        .build()))
    .build();
```

**With the 'id' attribute of the 'bar' widget modified to 21**

This produces the results:

```
3 diffs
  - type = child nodelist sequence
  - message = Expected child nodelist sequence '1' but was '2' - comparing <ns2:widget...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[2] to <ns2:widget...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[3]
  - type = attribute value
  - message = Expected attribute value '19' but was '21' - comparing <ns2:widget id="19"...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[2]/@id to <ns2:widget id="21"...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[3]/@id
  - type = child
  - message = Expected child 'null' but was '{com.xyz}widget' - comparing <NULL> to <ns2:widget...> at /policy[1]/widgets[1]/widget[2]
```

This seems to correctly be saying 'widget 2 was moved to widget 3, widget 2's id changed from 19 to widget 3's id value of 21, and a new widget 2 was added.'

The only thing still missing is how to do this for arbitrary tags and attributes.